# Mina deploy rvm_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, rvm

Having problem with Mina Deploy on Rails 4 app?

```
user$ mina deploy
root@xx.xx.xxx.xx's password:
-----> Using RVM environment 'ruby-2.1.0'
! Ruby Version Manager not found
! If RVM is installed, check your :rvm_path setting.
Connection closed.

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 256
```

Comment: provide `which rvm` on remote pc.

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm

Comment: does your set mina's `rvm_path` up to `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`?

Comment: Nope.I don't because i try also to use rbenv but again it says Bundle: command not found.

Comment: try to set `rvm_path` and give the answer

Comment: Hello guys, I have a exact same problem. When I try `rvm_path` it shows me: `rvm_path: command not found`. Any idea?. My rvm path is `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm`

Comment: Nope, It won't work. How about rbenv?

Answer (score 5):

Add the command below in your basic settings of `deploy.rb` file which will let mina find the rvm path.

`set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm'`

Then run `mina deploy` again.

Answer (score 3):

For latest mina deployment set it as follows:

```
set :rvm_use_path, '/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```